# Accessing a UK API from EC2

Tags: java, http, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I have a java web application running on Amazon EC2 (on a single instance, running in the Ireland EU West region), which makes HTTP requests to UK based sites and APIs (as it happens, using the Apache HttpClient).
When running on a local Tomcat server here in the UK, everything works as expected, but when deployed on EC2, the application is no longer making requests from the UK, so everything breaks down (as the websites restrict access from outside the UK and the APIs return US region specific data).
The obvious solution seems to be to route the HTTP requests via a UK proxy server, which I'd expect would resolve the issue, but would degrade performance a little and provide an extra point of failure (e.g. if the proxy server were blacklisted). As it's a web application, I could also move some of the request logic out to the browser (e.g. through XHR GETs in Javascript), though there's a fair amount of processing to be done, and I'd rather keep the bulk of it server side.
Is there any way to configure EC2 or the requests to get around this issue, or is there an alternative/better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Sending "en-gb" in the Accept-Language header probably won't work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks, was worth a shot, but as expected, didn't do the trick unfortunately